# Entering Expression IEnumerable<String> in TFS Workflow

Tags: templates, msbuild-task

The MSBuild activity in the DefaultTemplate.xaml accepts an expression for the Targets property.  What is the syntax for the expression I need to enter here?  All my efforts so far have failed.

Here is my latest failed attempt:

List(Of String) From () {"\Server1\Folder1"}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe Targets is more accurately used for the targetted framework and configuration - i.e. x86 Release mode